# What combo are ultralisks good against in WoL?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

I find that when coming up against a large Marine/Marauder group I often lose even when I have about 10 ultralisks.

It is only in a few situations, in late 4v4 games, that I have been able to go for ultralisks, but then they just died instantly.

I probably made some tactical mistakes, but I want to learn *when* to go for ultralisks and what combo they're good against in WoL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terran diamond / master player.

**Ultralisk are great when your opponent goes for bio / soft targets.**
Do not go for Ultras versus a mech. build.

The trick is to do it at the right time in-game. Ultralisks are endgame units.
So producing them to early will empty out your economy to early!
You need at least 3 mining bases.

And combine your army with Zerglings and Infestor!
Do not forget your upgrades!

Avoid Ultralisks when facing a Protoss, they are mostly mech., and can easily take out your Ultralisks.

So to round up things. When your Terran opponent goes for a bio build:

- Early game: Zerglings and Banelings
- Mid game: Zerglings, Banelings and Infestors
- Late game: Zerglings, Infestors and Ultralisks.

These are my recommendations!

Comment: I have to disagree with a lot of this answer. Ultralisks can be pretty ineffective against even a mediocre MM&M ball if the marauders have concussive shells. The Terran can just kite your army all day; even if you get a fungal down the ultras will be so slow by the time they start doing splash damage they're at half health.

I've found that ultralisks are pretty effective against breaking siege lines or using them to tank high damage while the rest of your army does the work, as Robotnik said.

Ultras are also quite effective against a heavy colossi build or large groups of stalkers.

Comment: I hear you Murkantilism. Regarding Marauders, that's what the Zerglings are for, and I would assume a descent spread of Creep, as its a daring move to engage off Creep for the Zerg player. And yes Ultralisks can be good versus Colossi, though it would be preferable with Broodlords and Curroptors.

Answer (score 2):

I don't play zerg often enough, but I don't see *just* ultralisks in play - they are usually backed up by an army of roach/hydras and are used to tank damage so that the roach/hydra combo can deal the actual damage.

In 4v4 the best tactical decision you can make is working with your teammates to attack/defend together. I've actually played a 4v4 where we got rolled by Ultralisk/Roach/Marine/Medivac - The (20) medivacs were healing the Ultralisks, and there was like 20 of them as well (it was PTTZ v TTZZ). Fun game though.

As for 'When' you should go ultralisks - it depends on whether that is your ultimate goal of your build. A lot of Zerg I see transition from 'ling-roach to Infestor/Roach/Hydra backed (eventually) by brood lords - and that's where they stop. If you want a power push into a heavily fortified base, then you could go ultralisk, but they should be backed up by other units to deal the brunt of the damage.